# How to recover data from Hard Disk that is DISKPART cleaned?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, diskpart

By mistake, I used **DISKPART clean** to switch between MBR and GPT hard disk types to install windows. So whole data is lost and I have reinstalled Windows 10 on it. During installation, I formatted the cleaned disk and now I have only 1 drive (C drive) with space **939 GB** (my original hard drive is 1 TB. I had 3-4 partitions on it before cleaning it).

I hope you understand the current status of my hard disk. Now is there any way to recover the partitions as well as the data safely?

Comment: I am not sure, but try using Recover4All. It used to be a commercial software and I have personally used this while doing Diskpart mistakes.

Comment: I have recovered most of the important data using Data Rescue PC3 software. Thank you by the way :)

Comment: @VikasKumar then you should post a self-answer. :P

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you've done with the disk.

If all you've done is run clean, and then you didn't touch the disk, there's a good chance you can rebuild most of the file system - there's a number of recovery tools out there :  [I've done this at least once - clean doesn't do much damage, but the rebuild takes a long time]
http://www.gfi.com/blog/the-top-23-free-data-recovery-tools/

If you ran clean then  quick formatted, there's a slim chance you may be able to recover - probably a better chance if the new format is a different filesystem than the old one. You'll have to remember what each partition's file system is though.

If you've cleaned, formatted, then installed an OS, I don't think there's any recovering, at least not with any standardized tools. The OS install (especially windows) will create a swap partition, probably a boot partition, and write to a bunch of the disk. The partitions at the end of the disk may still be there, but they will be hard to find and it won't be done in 10 minutes.

The most important thing to do when you think you messed up a drive is ABSOLUTELY NOTHING. most filesystem operations only mark data as available to be overwritten - rarely is the data actually gone.

Comment: «but they will be hard to find» Actually, if they are not overwritten they can be easily found with the usual tools, like `testdisk`. Partially overwritten partitions require more thorough reconstruction but it's still possible to save some of the files.